# what is the difference between stateful and stateless transformation in Kstreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am a beginner to Kstreams and I went through the documentation but I cannot seem to grasp the difference between these two, a simple explanation with an example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What OneCricketer said is correct. I am posting this answer just to explain with now example. In a nutshel, `stateful` operations are dependent on previous events of the stream whereas `stateless` operations are not. So, take this example of count events.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);
KTable<String, Count> aggregate = stream
      .peek((key, value) -> log.info("received key: {}, value: {}", key, value))
      .filter((key, value) -> /* filter events with value is ____ */)
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(new Initializer<Count>() {
                    @Override
                    public Count apply() {
                        return new Count("", 0);
                    }
                }, new Aggregator<String, String, Count>() {
                    @Override
                    public Count apply(String k, String v, Count aggKeyCount) {
                        Integer currentCount = aggKeyCount.getCount();
                        return new Count(k, currentCount + 1);
                    }
                });
                
aggregate.toStream()
         .map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, v.getCount()))
         .peek((key, value) -> log.info("emitting key: {}, value: {}", key, value))
         .to(COUNTS_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));
```

The operations `groupByKey`, `aggregate`, `filter`, `map` are transforming the events in some way (the `peek` does not transform the events). The transformations `groupByKey`, `filter` and `map` are `stateless` because they potentially modify the current events that they are processing (they do not care about the previous events). The `aggregate` transformation is counting the number of events, so it is summing them up. Therefore it depends on the previous events. Not that it has an `Initializer` of `Count("", 0)` and it aggregates events one by one on `Count(k, currentCount + 1)` that is based on the previous counter `aggKeyCount`.

Moreover, the concept of `stateless` and `stateful` is not on `KStream` of Kafka. It is on all Processing engines such as Hadoop MapReduce, [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html), [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/), Apache Storm. And it is also present on any processing pipeline, such as Java Stream (e.g.: `map`, `reduce`, `flatmap`, `filter`), [Akka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902354/akka-streams-state-in-a-flow), [project reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018238/2096986).

Comment: thank you for the example, it helped in understanding the concept better

Answer (score 6):

Aggregation and joins requires state - an initial accumulator or grouping that's carried through the topology

Filtering, branching, mapping or iterating the stream require no state - one message comes in, zero or one messages come out

Worth pointing out that the groupBy functions are considered stateless

Comment: Do you know why join operations are stateful? What kind of data should be stored internally?

Comment: Joins in KStreams typically require some type of time-window, so all data within that window is collected into memory, then compared against values in another topic within the same time frame.